# Definition - filter basis

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, filters

In the Trèves' book, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels he defines:

> A family $\mathscr{B}$ of subset of $E$ is a *basis* of a filter $\mathscr{F}$ on $E$ if the following two conditions are satisfied:
>
> $BF_1)$ $\mathscr{B} \subset \mathscr{F}$, i.e., any subset which belongs to $\mathscr{B}$ must belong to $\mathscr{F}$.
>
> $BF_2)$ Every subset of $E$ belonging to $\mathscr{F}$ contains some subset of $E$ which belongs to $\mathscr{B}$.

**My question:** Do I need to assume that $\mathscr{B}$ is non-empty? Or does that follow immediately from the definition?

Comment: If $\mathscr{B}=\varnothing$, the second condition implies that $\mathscr{F}=\varnothing$ as well. Does Trèves allow $\varnothing$ as a filter? If not — and one generally does not — then it does follow from the definition that $\mathscr{F}\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition (at least all that I know of) of a filter $\mathscr{F}$ is non-empty (we can state that for sure that $E \in \mathscr{F}$) , so $BF_2$ forces that $\mathscr{B}$ is non-empty, to contain a subset of $E$.